# Passing a variable through another PHP file and print it out

Tags: php, variables, scope, echo

I try to pass a variable which is stored in another php file to a second file, the content of the variable should printed out. But I can't see any result, can someone help me?

**dp.php**

```
include('config.php');

function getTitle() {
    echo $title;
}
```

**config.php**

```
<?php

$title= "some test title";

?>
```

Comment: Read about variable scope: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Additionally, if you want to use an external variable in a function or closure, you can utilize the `use` keyword like that:

`$title = "some test title";`

`function doSomething() use ($title) { echo $title; }`

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
include('config.php');

function getTitle() use ($title) {
    echo $title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$title is not in the scope of the function getTitle therefore nothing is going to be printed.

Try:

```
include('config.php');

function getTitle($title) {
    echo $title;
}

getTitle($title);
```

Answer (score 0):

Call that function like this to echo it out

```
getTitle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**dp.php**

```
include('config.php');

function getTitle() {
    echo _Title;
}
```

**config.php**

```
<?php

define("_Title", "Some title text");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider passing the value of `$title` to your function, but if you can't, you can use `global`. You must call the function for it to be invoked.

```
include('config.php');

function getTitle() {
    global $title;
    echo $title;
}

getTitle();
```